# Why was I awarded less stars than other team member?

Tags: battle-bay

This is result of one of battles in Battle Bay.

[image]

In this image, you can see that I (SachinShekhar) have got 2 stars and Queen_LA has got 3 stars when:

- I have inflicted more damage than she has.
- I have destroyed more ships than she has.
- I remained alive in the end, but she didn't.

Where's the catch? Why did I get less stars than Queen_LA?

Answer (score 1):

well on the infamy front, it mostly is the other way round. similar damage will get more stars on the boat with lower infamy. I have also noticed it is based on how you play in the battle. Queen here probably confronted all the attackers head on, taking all the fire while the rest of you were shooting. Alternately you probably took cover behind a few ships while shooting all along...or were hidden from the scene of action for quite some time.

Answer (score -1):

Look at your infamy and then theirs:

- Yours: 680
- Theirs: 691

The higher the infamy : the higher the stars

Comment: That's totally wrong. See the right hand side: A guy with 694 infamy got 0 stars, but 3 guys with less infamy got 1 star.